# EF Entitystate delete 1 record from Many To Many

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

So I try to delete 1 record from a many to many table. However, it doesn't delete anything?

I try to delete the record where the UserId == the Id of the logged in user and where the GroupId == the id is the id given with the link from the many to many table called GroupUser (with the fields: UserId and GroupId):

```
    public IActionResult UnSubscribe(Int16 id)
    {
        if(User.GetUserId() != null)
        {
            GroupUser groupToDel = _MyContext.GroupUser.Where(g => g.GroupId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            groupToDel.UserId+=User.GetUserId();

            _MyContext.Entry(groupToDel).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            _MyContext.SaveChanges(); 
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("There was an Error!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: see here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/delete-many-to-many-entities-in-entity-framework.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You're making this more difficult than it is I think, you should try just doing this:

```
GroupUser groupToDel = _MyContext.GroupUser.Where(g => g.GroupId == groupid 
                                                  && g.UserId == userid).First();

_MyContext.GroupUser.Remove(groupToDel);
_MyContext.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Sadly, this did not work, It just sends me to the link /Unsubscribe/GroupId. But maybe you are right I am looking it too far :D

Comment: `_MyContext` is just your class which inherits from `DbContext` right? I don't see how that code can redirect you. If it there are no exceptions thrown and `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Group");` is called, it should've been removed from the database

Comment: That's because of my link? `                                    <a asp-controller="Group" asp-action="UnSubscribe" asp-route-id="@groups.Id" 
                                    class="mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                                    UnSubscribe
                                    </a>`